# Mental block with os.walk - want to process a file not the filename string

Tags: python, os.walk

Trying to implement a little script to move the older log files out of apache (actually using a simple bash script to do this in 'real life' - this is just an exercise to practice using Python). I'm getting the filename as a string as the variable f, but I want this to actually be a file when i pass it to self.processFile(root, f, age, inString).

I tried opening the actual file a few different ways, but I'm missing the target, and end up getting an error, a path that doesn't always seem to be correct, or just a string. I'll blame it on the late night, but I'm blanking on the best way to open f as a file right before passing to self.processFile (where it will be gzipped). Usually its something very simple that i'm missing, so I have to assume that's the case here. I'd appreciate any constructive advice/direction.

```
 """recursive walk through /usr/local/apache2.2/logs"""
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
            for f in files:
                m=self.fileFormatRegex.match(f)
                if m:
                    if (('access_log.' in f) or
                        ('error.' in f) or
                        ('access.' in f) or
                        ('error_log.' in f) or
                        ('mod_jk.log.' in f)):
                        #This is where i'd like to open the file using the filename f
                        self.processFile(root, f, age, inString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.abspath`:

```
self.processFile(root, open(os.path.abspath(f)), age, inString)
```

Like so:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
    for f in files:
        m=self.fileFormatRegex.match(f)
        if m:
            if (set('access_log.', 'error.', 'access.', 'error_log.','mod_jk.log.').intersection(set(f))):
                self.processFile(root, open(os.path.abspath(f)), age, inString)
```

Or `os.path.join`:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
    for f in files:
        m=self.fileFormatRegex.match(f)
        if m:
            if (set('access_log.', 'error.', 'access.', 'error_log.','mod_jk.log.').intersection(set(f))):
             self.processFile(root, open(os.path.join(r"/", root, f)), age, inString)
             # Sometimes the leading / isnt necessary, like this:
             # self.processFile(root, open(os.path.join(root, f)), age, inString)
```

More about [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)

---

Yet another way using `file()` instead of `open()` (does almost the same thing as open):

```
self.processFile(root, file(os.path.join(root, f), "r"), age, inString)
self.processFile(root, file(os.path.abspath(f), "r+"), age, inString)
```

Comment: Thanks chown. I tried this and it worked. I thought I'd tried this earlier and had it fail, but i may have fat-fingered something during the earlier trial.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed up @jonny!  Happy to help.

Comment: if f.startswith(('access_log.', 'error.', 'acess.', 'error_log.', 'mod_jk.log/'))

Comment: sadly i had this snippet working in another function a few lines down from the problem area. I just realized this and i am feeling very much like Homer Simpson right now.

Comment: `file` and `open` do *exactly* the same thing, as they are two different names for the same command.

Comment: Almost, `file()` is a `file` type constructor, and `open` is a function that constructs and returns a `file` object.  They achieve the same end, but not technically the exact same.

Comment: And `file` goes away in Python 3, so `open` or `io.open` are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

```
base = "/some/path"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base):
    for f in files:
        thefile = file(os.path.join(root, f))
```

You'll have to join the `root` argument to each of the `files` argument to get a path to the actual file.

Comment: there is no `os.join`, did you mean `os.path.join`?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy - Thanks for taking the time to answer. This would have also worked, and in fact i have a very similar snippet a few lines down from the area i was having a problem with. As usual it was me that was the issue, and it was a simple solution I was blanking on for some reason.